# Wildcard on DocumentRoot for virtualhost

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain, wildcard, wildcard-subdomain

i use this config in apache2 for wildcard subdomain and works good :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/
  ServerName sumdomains.example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) /%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

this means, a request to http://user.example.com/foo.html will fetch the file /var/www/**user.example.com**/foo.html.

but i want request to http://**user**.example.com/foo.html fetch file from /var/www/**user**/foo.html.

which wildcard should am i use for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set rewrite rule grab the sub.domain and redirect to /sub/requestedFile

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)\.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.+) /%1/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Or set VirtualDocumentRoot with %-1 representing the sub domain.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%-1
  ServerName sumdomains.example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```