# Using Dynamic paths in Apache httpd.conf file

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, httpd.conf, dynamic

I know how to set up multiple hosts in an apache httpd.conf file but is it possible to make that dynamic.

If I put my folders in directories like this.

```
c:\
   development\
               websites\
                        SiteA
                        SiteB
                        SiteC
```

Can I write my httpd.conf file in a way like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName *.example.com
DocumentRoot "c:/development/Websites/%1/"

</VirtualHost>
```

where `%1`or other variable marker is SiteA if the user visits sitea.example.com etc  or event if siteA has to be a fully qualified domain that is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply: **no**.

A `DocumentRoot` has to be a single directory on the server, and wildcards are not allowed.

You *may* be able to get the behaviour you're after by using `RewriteRule` statements mentioned in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/498970/163830), but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

At least in 2.4 you can:

```
<Macro virty $name>
<VirtualHost $name:80>

ServerName $name.example.com
DocumentRoot "c:/development/Websites/$name/"

</VirtualHost>
</Macro>

Use virty SiteA
Use virty SiteB
Use virty SiteC
```